# R ggplot2 question - working with factors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got a dataset that looks like this...

> ```
> mine tonnes week
> AA   112    41
> AA   114    41
> AA   119    41
> BB   108    41 
> BB   112    41
> AA   110    42
> AA   109    42
> AA   102    43
> AA   101    43
> ```

And I want to create a boxplot in ggplot2 to show the distribution of tonnes for each week. But I only want results from mine AA.

I thought it would work like this....

```
qplot(factor(week), tonnes[mine == "AA"], data = sql_results, geom = "boxplot")
```

But instead, I get this error.

```
Error in data.frame(x = c(13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L,  :

  arguments imply differing number of rows: 423100, 109436
```

It's probably dead simple, but I'm not having much luck figuring the right way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

close. In your example you created a subset of tonnes, but not of week.

```
sql_results<-structure(list(mine = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("AA", "BB"), class = "factor"), tonnes = c(112, 
114, 119, 108, 112, 110, 109, 102, 101), week = c(41, 41, 41, 
41, 41, 42, 42, 43, 43)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9"), .Names = c("mine", "tonnes", "week"), class = "data.frame")

qplot(factor(week), tonnes, data = subset(sql_results,mine=="AA"), geom = "boxplot")
```